# Mac OS X 10.5.8 not accepting Tor 4.0.1

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I am trying to load Tor 4.0.1 on my MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5.8. The file arrives with the "no entry" sign on it and will not load. Are there any solutions? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Tor 4.0.1 requires Mac OS 10.6+. 10.5.8 is not supported.

See https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#mac